# getJSON returns "undefined" value

Tags: jquery, json, api

I am trying to learn how to make API calls with JSON and I am getting an "undefined" result. The API is for an invoice web app ([www.curdbee.com](http://www.curdbee.com)) and I am wanting the results to be a list of each client name. Right now, I get a list but each result is "undefined". Here is my jQuery code so far:

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://nspirelab.curdbee.com/clients.json?api_token=', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            $('#results').append('<div class="invoice">' + item.name + '</div>');
        });
    });
});
```

Also, in the actual script, my api token is included.

Comment: Well, what does the returned JSON look like? Can you do a `console.log(data);`?

Comment: It is a list of "undefined". http://imgur.com/iCArK

Comment: I don't see where you're pasting in your api_token? Don't share w/us :) But are you sure you're passing it in?

Comment: @user715564: I was asking about the *actual* JSON response - not what you're writing to the screen.

Comment: It's in the actual script, I just didn't want to included it in the question.

Comment: @user715564 - What happens if you load the URL in your browser? I'd suggest starting there. Make sure the request is correct. Good luck!

Comment: I am sorry I am completely new to this! How would I find out the actual json response?

Comment: `https://nspirelab.curdbee.com/clients.json?api_token=` load that in your address bar, just like you would any other web page. You should see JSON. (Don't forget the API token!)

Comment: Ok, when I load up the url all of the info is presented. All of the clients show up in the browser as well as their specific details. In my test run I am just trying to get a list of the clients name. Is "item.name" not what I should be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the API docs for [`/clients`](http://curdbee.com/api/clients/), you're missing a property lookup -- the `client` of `item.client.name`.

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://nspirelab.curdbee.com/clients.json?api_token=', function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            $('#results').append('<div class="invoice">' + item.client.name + '</div>');
        });
    });
});
```

This is needed to retrieve values of the inner objects:

```
[                                  // == data
    {                                  // == item
        "client": {                        // == item.client
            "id": 6364,                        // == item.client.id
            "name": "7Seven7 Insurance Inc",   // == item.client.name
            ...
        }
    },
    ...
]
```